# How to find duplicate record count of cell value between some start row and end row of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert the excel formula `=COUNTIF(A4:A11,A4)` to python code.
Here `A4` is the start row and `A11` is end row of my selection and I want to find how many times the value in the cell `A4` occurs in the cells from `A4` row to `A11`.

I have loaded the data from an excel file into a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: How are you storing your data in python?  Are you loading it into a pandas DataFrame?  as nested lists?  as numpy array?, etc?  From your tags, I assume dataframe but it's not clear from your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  To get a better answer, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Yes, I am loading data in pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example dataframe.

```
In [307]: df
Out[307]:
    a
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   1
5   1
6   4
7   5
8   1
9   1
10  5
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  1

In [308]: df[df['a'] == df['a'].iloc[4]]['a'].loc[4:11].count()
Out[308]: 4
```

Or,

```
In [315]: df[df['a'] == df['a'].iloc[4]].loc[4:11, 'a'].count()
Out[315]: 4
```

Or,

```
In [323]: df.loc[4:11].query('a== @df.a.iloc[4]')['a'].count()
Out[323]: 4
```

Or,

```
In [319]: df.loc[4:11, 'a'].eq(df.a.iloc[4]).sum()
Out[319]: 4
```

Comment: Okay. Suppose  Field or column "A" having 100 records in dataframe then I want to find How many times 1st row/index value is repeated between 1st  and 10th row/index in dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by populating the DataFrame (you're probably using read_csv or something).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5,1, 0, 1, 3, 7, 9]})
```

You can access a slice of the dataframe with

```
df[4:11+1] # does the same thing as `A4:A11` in terms of grabbing only those rows
```

From here, we want to limit to only values that match `A4`.  We do that with

```
df[4:11+1][df["a"] == df["a"][4]]
```

And then, we want to count those occurrences:

```
df[4:11+1][df["a"] == df["a"][4]]["a"].count()
```

Comment: Note that you may need to consider if you're using 0-indexing or 1-indexing

Answer (score 0):

using numpy

```
np.count_nonzero(np.in1d(df['a'][4:12],df['a'][4]))
```